# java.nio.file.DirectoryStream in WAR

Tags: java, file, nio

I'm trying to work with nio's way to read files from directory.
I've come across the [java.nio.file.DirectoryStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html)
which is cool because now I don't need to maintain a list of files in the directory by myself and I like this idea.

Now, my code is going to be run inside the WAR so that it will read the resources (say some xml files) packed inside jars inside this WAR.

I couldn't find a good example of working with DirectoryStream like this. So my question is how can I use this approach (not necessarily this particular class of course)  in my situation?

Maybe there are some thirdparties that provide the similar abstraction...

In addition I would like to test this code from my unit test (which means that ideally this code shouldn't really assume that it runs inside/outside the WAR if its possible of course).

Thanks and have a nice day

Comment: Use `getClass().getResource("/...") to get the `jar:file/...` URL. You might need the zip FileSystem to bridge resource to File. Using getResource covers both cases: where the war is either unpacked (`file:`) or stays packed. Best tested with a jar.

Comment: Items in a WAR file aren't directories or files. They are resources.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it answers my question. I'm aware of this method, but what I really want is not to maintain the "/..." in a list. I don't know which files reside in my folder, I just know where the folder is. So In a traditional approach I can read the list of resources and then iterate one-by-one. But in this case I have to maintain this list in my code, this is something I want to avoid...

Comment: It isn't intended to answer your question. It's a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a temporary folder and copying the needed resources into this directory. Now you can use the DirectoryStream-Class, because the files are placed in the filesystem.